# How to make a an object property with a defined type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Using KendoReact in SPFx web part I need to populate a line like so:

```
<GridColumn field={column.field} key={index} title={column.title} width={column.width}
        filter={column.filter}   />;
```

So feeding { field: "Title", title: "Pr-Job" }, is OK because field and title are defined as 
"`(JSX attribute) GridColumnProps.title?: string`"

but filter gives me an error because filter is defined as "`(JSX attribute) GridColumnProps.filter?: "boolean" | "date" | "numeric" | "text" "`

what can I do in the line

```
   filter={????column.filter ??} //What should the syntax be?
```

to make it accept the property value?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change `column.filter` type, the possible workaround is to use [`as` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#the-as-operator). You can't use `<type>` type assertion with jsx.

```js
   filter={column.filter as any}
```

Comment: Wow That was super simple Thanks